# Single Active Camera from main scene for multiple scenes in Unity 3D AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, scene-manager

I am stuck in a situation in my project. I will try to explain in as simple as possible.
In my project there are three scenes and I am trying to merge on a button click. And when the merge is occurring, I want this three scenes work with a single camera.

Lets say the three scenes are S1, S2, and S3. S1 is the main scene and the other two are called as additive scene using `SceneManager.LoadScene("S2", LoadSceneMode.Additive)` and `SceneManager.LoadScene("S3", LoadSceneMode.Additive)`. Since, S2 is using Unity MARS, I made sure all the scenes have MARS Session.
There are three buttons S1, one used for Plane Detection Control, and other two for the Scenes.

But my issue is that, although I am adding the scene as additive scene, when the new scenes gets load, all the work of previous scenes disappears. I tried to keep MARS session in S1 and removing them from other scenes, but in that case the other scenes didn't work.

I have tried to replace MARS Session with normal AR Session Origin and XR Origin but it didn't worked either. Looked for solutions too, but most of the results are Multiple Camera in one scene.

Please tell me if there is a way to do this or should I change the way I am approaching. Or if any has ever did something like that. Any form of source will be great and helpful.
If any other information is required, I will try my best to provide it.

Thank you in advance...